# LUA pipe to cygwin in WIn 7 x64 - os.execute

Tags: linux, lua, windows-7, netcat, piping

so for starters I am a novice to programming overall, especially with Linux - I have had success piping this string in ubuntu to netcat:
echo bla bla bla | nc -w 2 192.168.1.10 43333

The Lua program does this with the following lines of code:

runcommand = "echo " .. bla .."" .. bla .. "" .. bla .. " | nc -w " .. 2 .. " " .. (IP) .. " " .. (Port) .. " ";

os.execute(runcommand);

I wanted to get this working the same way in Windows 7 , and I installed Cygwin on my windows 7 machine. Copy paste of this string into Cygwin works-yay!

But how do I send this from a Lua program in windows to do this? I guess what i'm trying to do is send this string directly to Cygwin, but this Lua code doesn't work (the os.execute command anyway)

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

1) What I need to have installed on windows to do this (Lua libraries/Linux libraries etc)

2)How I need to change the Lua code on my windows machine to make this happen

3) Any other obvious things i'm missing

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This does work for me:

```
c = [[cd /d C:\cygwin\bin && bash.exe -c "cd /cygdrive/c && /bin/ls | /bin/wc"]]
print(io.popen(c):read'*a')   -->      17      22     194
```